# Error Datatype does not contains EmailAddress

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I have an error when I try to create a login/registration and [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)] in VS 2019. Do you have any ideas how i get pass this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not put images of code, put your code.
Please take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and/or [How to create minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to declare the namespace: `using DataAnnotationsExtensions`. You can add their library with NuGet package.

OR

You could use the usual `DataAnnotations` library by just using `[EmailAddress]`

`using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`